# Flutter: child button filling container size with explicit size

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to have a button nested in a container with a specific background color. I'm setting the height on the `Container` and on the `MaterialButton` nested within. I would expect the `MaterialButton` to maintain it's height of 40, while in the container of height 100. Instead, the `MaterialButton` is stretch to the height and width of the container.[image]

```
Container(
                    color: lightBackground,
                    height: 100,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: MaterialButton(
                      height: 40,
                      child: Text('Hi'),
                      color: primaryColor,
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ))
```

Anyone know how to get round this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is to set `alignment: Alignment.center` for the `Container`, or wrap the `Button` with a `Center` widget.

For example:

```
Container(
   height: 100,
   alignment: Alignment.center,
   child: ...
)
```

The long explanation has to do with Flutter Layout Constraints. You can read more about it at the [official doc here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints).